# How to disable transition on navigation in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am creating a header that is initially transparent (I can choose which pages have transparent header).

When scrolling to certain position, header's background color becomes solid white with transition, and vise versa. But the issue is that this transition also applies on header's background change when navigating.

So let's say, I am on a certain page where I decide my header to be solid. What I want is that when I navigate from this page to another page where header is supposed to be transparent, it changes without transition.

But when I, for example, navigate from the page with solid header to the page with transparent header, it changes with transition, which makes it look bad.

I only want header transition when scrolling, while on navigation my header changes immediately.

**header.component.ts:**

```ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderService } from '../shared/header.service';
import { ScrollService } from '../shared/scroll.service';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() drawer!: MatSidenav;
  headerHeight: number;
  private isHeaderTransparent = false;
  private isHeaderSolidOnScroll = false;
  private isNavigating = false;


  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private headerService: HeaderService,
    private scrollService: ScrollService,
  ) {
    this.headerHeight = 0;
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.isNavigating = true;
      } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.isNavigating = false;
        const currentRoute = this.router.url;
        const isTransparent = this.headerService.isRouteTransparent(currentRoute);
        this.isHeaderTransparent = isTransparent;
        this.isHeaderSolidOnScroll = false;
        this.updateHeaderStyle();
        this.adjustMainPadding();
      }
    });
  } 

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.isNavigating = true;
      } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.isNavigating = false;
        const currentRoute = this.router.url;
        const isTransparent = this.headerService.isRouteTransparent(currentRoute);
        this.isHeaderTransparent = isTransparent;
        this.isHeaderSolidOnScroll = false;
        this.updateHeaderStyle();
        this.adjustMainPadding();
      }
    });
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: Event): void {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    const currentRoute = this.router.url;
    const isRouteTransparent = this.headerService.isRouteTransparent(currentRoute);
    if (isRouteTransparent || scrollPosition < 150) {
      this.isHeaderTransparent = isRouteTransparent;
      this.adjustMainPadding();
      this.updateHeaderStyle();
    }
    if (isRouteTransparent && scrollPosition >= 150) {
      this.isHeaderSolidOnScroll = true;
    } else {
      this.isHeaderSolidOnScroll = false;
    }
  }

  private updateHeaderStyle(): void {
    const header = document.getElementById('main-header') as HTMLElement;
    if (!this.isNavigating && this.isHeaderTransparent && !this.isHeaderSolidOnScroll) {
      header.classList.add('transparent-header');
      header.classList.remove('disable-transition');
    } else {
      header.classList.remove('transparent-header');
      if (this.isNavigating) {
        header.classList.add('disable-transition');
      }
    }
  }
```

**header.component.scss:**

```css
.header {
    // other styles
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.transparent-header {
    transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
}

.disable-transition {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

I tried assigning `.disable-transition` class to my header when navigating, but it's not working.

I want to find a better solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean that the `disable-transition` class isn't doing what you expect, or do you mean that it's not being applied correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly might be happening here, but overall your logic for this looks solid to me.

The only odd thing I see is that you are directly changing the class list on the header element without going through Angular. In general this is a bad practice in Angular since you are making DOM modifications without Angular knowing about it.

The easiest way to fix this is to probably have the classes applied via `ngClass` in the template and then just some boolean logic in your function

```ts
headerStateTransparent = false;
headerStateDisabledTransition = false;

private updateHeaderStyle(): void {
  this.headerStateTransparent = false;
  this.headerStateDisabledTransition = false;

  const header = document.getElementById('main-header') as HTMLElement;
  if (!this.isNavigating && this.isHeaderTransparent && !this.isHeaderSolidOnScroll) {
    this.headerStateTransparent = true;
    this.headerStateDisabledTransition = false;
  } else {
    this.headerStateTransparent = false;
    if (this.isNavigating) {
      this.headerStateDisabledTransition = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header"
        [ngClass]="{
          'disable-transition': headerStateDisabledTransition,
          'transparent-header': headerStateTransparent
        }">
  Look at my header!
</header>
```

The logic in there might not be perfect for exactly what you need and you may want to rename some variables though since you already have `isHeaderTransparent` and I just added `headerStateTransparent` - you get the idea though.